# Dúvida sobre certificado SSL

Tags: ssl

Fiz a realização para meu site com SSL agora há pouco, o processo deu certo e fiz pelo serviço grauito da Kinghost. O problema é que se eu coloco "www" antes o meu site mostra que está sem certificado (no caso sem o "www" aparece o certificado correto). Isso seria algum problema de código do meu site ou é com certificado?

Answer (score 0):

**Causa:**

Isso acontece porque o seu certificado aponta para um endereço - que se chama o Common Name.

**Pode resolver dessa forma:**

No seu caso endereço o seu Common Name deve ser www.seuendereço.com. Para garantir que voce pode usar seuendereco.com sem o www, deve usar um certificado com SAN (subject alternative name).

Comment: Eu estava estudando e vi que o problema do "www" é que não estava apontando para o https, estou tentando redirecionar no momento.